# About: get REST - returning a NotFound exception C#

Tags: c#, rest, google-api

Attempting to retrieve quota information from Google Drive via REST in C#.  Here is a code snippet:

```
public async Task<string> HasQuota(string accessToken) {
    var url = string.Concat(new string[] {                
                " https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about",
                "?access_token=" + accessToken,
                "&fields=quotaBytesTotal%2CquotaBytesUsed"
              });

    // Create the request.
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Create the response.
    var response = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                     request.BeginGetResponse, 
                     request.EndGetResponse, 
                     request
                   );

    if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription == "OK") {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I obtained the access_token I scoped the authentication request with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file and my test user granted permissions.  So as far as I aware I have the code requirements to execute this call.

However I get an NotFound exception when I attempt to execute this method.  The documentation says I can pass the access_token in the query string or add the Authorization header to the request i.e

```
request.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken);
```

Any ideas why I might be getting this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't enabled the Drive API option in the console...